# SharePoint 2013 - Accessing List data through web service from Sharepoint site, getting error 404

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, sharepoint-2013

I have been trying to get the list data from Sharepoint 2013 Site for many days but no luck. I stuck to the point where I don't know what could be the reason.

I have created a Sharepoint 2013 provider Hosted app on the development server. I have a list with data on the azure site (Production) and I am trying to access that data through the web service. Somehow I am able to connect to the service using URLs like "http: //mydomain/sites/sitename/_vti_bin/Lists. asmx" while adding the webreference to my project. This link is also showing the right values while Opened in browser with right credential but  the problem is that when I Click on create web reference button it gave me an error that wsdl cannot be downloaded.

So this is the message when I click on the service description , it doesn't show the xml file that supposed to show.

Please look at the link below for more clarification on my question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca6ec22b-bad5-466a-b811-08c515479ef1/sharepoint-2013-accessing-list-data-through-web-service-from-sharepoint-site-getting-error-404?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious